# how to configure java.xml.transform.transformer in spring

Tags: spring

How can  i configure java.xml.transform.Transformer in spring framework ? I need instance of transformer to transform xml to text via xslt. Hence it is critical that the configured transformer should have knowledge of xslt stylesheet. I am not using this in a web project, rather i am using this in a standalone java program.

Comment: You do mean `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, don't you?

Answer (score 5):

Well, the Java to configure a Transformer is like this:

```
Source stylesheetSource = new StreamSource(new File("/path/to/my/stylesheet.xslt"));
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(stylesheetSource);
```

If you really want to do this purely in Spring XML, this is the equivalent:

```
<bean id="stylesheetSource" class="javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource">
    <property name="systemId" value="/path/to/my/stylesheet.xslt"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transformerFactory" class="javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory" factory-method="newInstance"/>

<bean id="transformer" factory-bean="transformerFactory" factory-method="newTransformer">
    <constructor-arg ref="stylesheetSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was wondering why spring couldnt provide a bit more support so that all i need to do is pass name of my xslt and it should locate it on the classpath and build configure the transformer. 
Also , i believe i might need to set some properties on the transformer

Comment: Forgot to meansion scope=prototype

Comment: This is old, but I have to give people some advice to probably just not do this. Since beans are singletons by default in Spring even if you make the transformerfactory and transformer prototypes, it will be really easy for another developer to inject it in to a singleton bean and not realize they have just created a thread-safety issue. Instead I would create a helper class that wraps up these implementation details to make it much harder to get wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to get an instance of a `Transformer` from an appropriate `TransformerFactory`.  You can use the built-in xerces transformer factory or a 3rd party XSLT processor, like [saxonica](http://www.saxonica.com/).

Using Spring's IoC you can configure a Xerces XML transformer like this:

```
<bean id="transformerFactory" class="org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl" />
```

or a saxon XML transformer like this:

```
<bean id="transformerFactory" class="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" />
```

Once you have a TransformerFactory you can use dependency injection to get a new instance of a transformer either inside your bean or using the IoC.  Switching to be inside your class you might have some property, say `transFact` that you need to set:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="myClass">
   <property name="transFact" ref="transformerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Then in your class:

```
public class myClass {
    // ...

    private javax.xml.transformer.TransformerFactory transFact;


    public void myMethod(){
      StreamSource transformerStream = new StreamSource(getResourceAsStream(pathToXslt));
      javax.xml.transformer.Transformer myTrans = transFact.newTransformer(transformerStream);
      // now you've got a myTrans
    }

    // ...

    public setTransFact(javax.xml.transformer.TransformerFactory transFact){
      this.transFact = transFact;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can get a new transformer within IoC using the `factory-method` with a little more effort.

Answer (score 2):

I found this way to provide `xsl` file from the classpath:

```
<bean id="errorLogTransformer" factory-bean="transformerFactory" factory-method="newTransformer" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.transform.ResourceSource">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value>classpath:errorLog.xsl</value>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Pretty ugly, but it works!